# cakephp 2.x FormHelper radio ID

Tags: cakephp-2.4

When I use cakephp FormHelper like this

```
echo $this->Form->radio('searchDateType',array('0'=>'test0','1'=>'test1'),array(
                                'separator'=>'&nbsp;','default'=>2,'legend'=>false'));
```

I hope to get like this

```
<input type="radio" name="data[Project][searchDateType]" id="ProjectSearchDateType0" value="0" checked="checked">
<label for="ProjectSearchDateType0">test0</label>&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="data[Project][searchDateType]" id="ProjectSearchDateType1" value="1">
<label for="ProjectSearchDateType1">test1</label>
```

But in one of my centos server I get this

```
<input type="radio" name="data[Project][searchDateType]" id="ProjectSearchDateType" value="0" checked="checked">
<label for="ProjectSearchDateType">test0</label>&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="data[Project][searchDateType]" id="ProjectSearchDateType" value="1">
<label for="ProjectSearchDateType">test1</label>
```

The IDs are the same

Then I find the wrong is in Inflector::slug

```
preg_replace(array_keys($map), array_values($map), $string);
```

This return empty.

I don't know what's wrong with it,counld someone help me to solve it

Comment: I have three centos servers and the php.ini are the same,but why only one centos server has this problem

Comment: You should need to got form helper in lib->view->formhelper.php file and manually check . it have check it on my system but it works

Comment: I think my code is OK, may be something wrong with my centos setting,but I don't know where

Comment: The ID should be 'ProjectSearchDateType0' 'ProjectSearchDateType1'  and the '0' '1'  are return from Inflector::slug,so I think "preg_replace(array_keys($map), array_values($map), $string)" has something wrong

Comment: id generate through radio loop key . you need to open Lib->view->formhelper-> public function radio($fieldName, $options = array(), $attributes = array()) { } . In this function A loop has run on the basis of radio options foreach ($options as $optValue => $optTitle) { } check line by line in this. then you find the issue?

Comment: Yes,I check line by line,then I find this code has something wrong                                                                                                  $tagName = Inflector::camelize($attributes['id'] . '_' . Inflector::slug($optValue));  so that I find "Inflector::slug($optValue)" return empty

Comment: here $optValue is current foreach key value. this will return 0,1,2,3,4,5 . check $optValue at initial of the loop for each iteration .if this always 0 then try to manually assigned autoincrement value in a variable

Comment: i have check in my library thats working fine

Comment: e...thank you all the same,I will write the reason if I find it.